# What is the system/CMS used in this site?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, content-management-system

I`m interested how they take and illustrate the content of *.PDF files like img files in this [page](http://www.valerus-bg.com/category/chem-lab-equipment/11/).

And also they make list of pdf files [there](http://www.valerus-bg.com/chem-lab-certificates/)

I`m using drupal 7 and want to know "Can i make these 2 things in Drupal 7 ?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make something like that with these modules:

- Views (http://drupal.org/project/views) - to make the list of your files.
- PDFPreview (https://drupal.org/project/pdfpreview) - to make automatic image previews of the first page of your pdf (then you put these in the view created by Views module)

Both lists are very similar, with one difference - the first one will use PDFPreview image as a field formatter, the second one will just print out the raw file name (you can add the pdf icon with "rewrite the output of this field" functionality and few lines of CSS)